# How to mount a raw image?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am trying to mount a raw image in my ubuntu VM but it returns a mismatch type error:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ sudo kpartx -a -f -v xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
root@ubuntu:~$ cd /dev/mapper/
root@ubuntu:/dev/mapper$ ls
control  ubuntu--vg-root  ubuntu--vg-swap_1
root@ubuntu:/dev/mapper$ losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /home/usera/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
root@ubuntu:/dev/mapper$ sudo mkdir /tmp/foo
root@ubuntu:/dev/mapper$ mount /dev/loop
loop0         loop2         loop4         loop6         loop-control
loop1         loop3         loop5         loop7
root@ubuntu:/dev/mapper$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/foo/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I read up online and follow the instruction but the instruction said I should have a loop0s1 under /dev/mapper folder instead. But I don't see anything under /dev/mapper. Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks

Edit:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ file xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img: QEMU QCOW Image (v2), 2361393152 bytes

root@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
Disk xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img: 276.3 MiB, 289734656 bytes, 565888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Add the output of `file  /home/usera/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img` and `fdisk -l  /home/usera/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img`, please

Comment: Mouting an image only works as simple as you described if it is a single partition with a single filesystem on it - does this image have partitions or maybe even LVM ?

Comment: That is not a raw image. That's a QCOW2 image.